# Mocha + RequireJS in the browser - cannot instantiate _ui

Tags: javascript, requirejs, mocha.js

I am having a hard time trying to run tests with Mocha and RequireJS in the browser.

My attempt is based on https://gist.github.com/michaelcox/3800736

I had to diverge from that example, because my main issue is that `require('mocha')` always errors with "Module name "lib/mocha" has not been loaded yet for context".

But somehow magically I see that global Mocha is instantiated. I invoke it as a constructor, but the run of `new Mocha()` does not prepare the interface (`describe`, etc.)

I see that the problem is that an inner call to

```
this._ui = this._ui(this.suite);
```

leaves `this._ui` undefined, apparently because array `this.suite.tests` is empty, which is explainable as I still have to read the test suite file.

Here are the details. If anyone can shed some light, I'll be very grateful.

I start from a single HTML tag loading require.js with a data-main.

```
<script data-main="./js_modular/spec-runner" src="./js_modular/lib/require.js"></script>
```

My data-main file (not working!) is the following:

```
require.config({
  'paths': {
    'mocha': './lib/mocha',
    'chai': './lib/chai',
    'sinon': './lib/sinon-1.11.1'
  }
});

define(['require', 'exports', 'mocha'], (function(require, exports, mocha) {
    // mocha is undefined, but Mocha is not
    var mocha = new Mocha({ ui: 'bdd' }); // mocha misses the characteristic methods of the bdd interface, though...
    require([
      './geiesadts_test', // load of test file fails because describe is undefined
    ], function(require) {
      mocha.run(); // never got till here :-(
    });
}));
```

Thank you for your attention.